# Counting occurrence of specific character per gene in fasta file using python

Tags: python, counter, biopython

I have a fasta file as follows:

```
>SO_0001 
MTKIAILVGTTLGSSEYIADEMQAQLTPLGHEVHTFLHPTLDELKPYPLWILVSSTHGAGDLPDNLQPFC
KELLLNTPDLTQVKFALCAIGDSSYDTFCQGPEKLIEALEYSGAKAVVDKIQIDVQQDPVPEDPALAWLA
QWQDQI
>SO_0002  
MTTPVDAPKWPRQIPYIIASEACERFSFYGMRNILTPFLMTALLLSIPEELRGAVAKDVFHSFVIGVYFF
PLLGGWIADRFFGKYNTILWLSLIYCVGHAFLAIFEHSVQGFYTGLFLIALGSGGIKPLVSSFMGDQFDQ
>SO_0003 
MTTDTIVAQATAPGRGGVGIIRISGDKATNVAMAVLGHLPKPRYADYCYFKSASGQVIDQGIALFFKGPN
SFTGEDVLELQGHGGQIVLDMLIKRVLEVEGIRIAKPGEFSEQAFMNDKLDLTQAEAIADLIDATSEQAA
KSALQSLQGEFSKEVHELVDQVTHLRLYVEAAIDFPDEEVD
```

Where what follows the ">" is the gene ID and the letters following the ">" line are the corresponding sequences.  I want to parse through the file and count how many "C"'s there are in the sequence for each gene ID.  I would like my output file to be a tab delimited file like this:

```
SO_0001    Number of C's
SO_0002    Number of C's
SO_0003    Number of C's
```

and so on...

I am using python and thought this would be straight forward by making the gene IDs keys to a dictionary, but I have only done that with tab-delimited files and I am having trouble since each sequence is a different length and beneath the gene IDs.  Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already had data in the format you posted and don't want to delve into the specialized libraries you can try something like this.

```
with open('datafile.txt') as file:
  datalist = []
  for line in file:
    if line.startswith('>'):
      datalist.append([line.strip()[1:], ''])
    else:
      datalist[-1][1] += line.strip()
  for data in datalist:
    print(data[0], '   ', data[1].count('C'))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked really well.  Can I ask why do you add `''` in    `datalist.append([line.strip()[1:], ''])`   What is its purpose?  Thanks again!

Comment: I wasn't sure how many lines the sequence would be spread over.  It is used as a placeholder for the following lines that have sequence information.

Answer (score 4):

Searching for `biopython fasta` brings up [this page](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO), and modifying the example:

```
>>> from Bio import SeqIO
>>> with open("bio.fasta") as fp:
...         record_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(fp, "fasta"))
...
```

produces a dictionary of data looking like

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(record_dict)
{'SO_0001': SeqRecord(seq=Seq('MTKIAILVGTTLGSSEYIADEMQAQLTPLGHEVHTFLHPTLDELKPYPLWILVS...DQI', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='SO_0001', name='SO_0001', description='SO_0001', dbxrefs=[]),
 'SO_0002': SeqRecord(seq=Seq('MTTPVDAPKWPRQIPYIIASEACERFSFYGMRNILTPFLMTALLLSIPEELRGA...FDQ', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='SO_0002', name='SO_0002', description='SO_0002', dbxrefs=[]),
 'SO_0003': SeqRecord(seq=Seq('MTTDTIVAQATAPGRGGVGIIRISGDKATNVAMAVLGHLPKPRYADYCYFKSAS...EVD', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='SO_0003', name='SO_0003', description='SO_0003', dbxrefs=[])}
```

where we can access the records and count characters:

```
>>> record_dict["SO_0002"]
SeqRecord(seq=Seq('MTTPVDAPKWPRQIPYIIASEACERFSFYGMRNILTPFLMTALLLSIPEELRGA...FDQ', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='SO_0002', name='SO_0002', description='SO_0002', dbxrefs=[])
>>> record_dict["SO_0002"].seq
Seq('MTTPVDAPKWPRQIPYIIASEACERFSFYGMRNILTPFLMTALLLSIPEELRGA...FDQ', SingleLetterAlphabet())
>>> record_dict["SO_0002"].seq.count("C")
2
```

and so:

```
>>> count = {name: record.seq.count("C") for name, record in record_dict.items()}
>>> count
{'SO_0002': 2, 'SO_0003': 1, 'SO_0001': 3}
```

after which

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open("c_count.csv", "wb") as fp:
...     writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter="\t")
...     for k in sorted(count):
...         writer.writerow([k, count[k]])
```

produces a file like

```
localhost-2:coding $ cat c_count.csv 
SO_0001 3
SO_0002 2
SO_0003 1
```

Advice: don't rewrite a FASTA parser, use an existing one; and don't reimplement the `csv` module.

Comment: Thanks for the step by step!  Definitely will give this a try too.